# How to parse static text in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, function, parsing, object

I have a String that contains a function as a String. This String is returned by the server:

```
var funcStr = "function() {
    console.log('this is a sample function');
}";
```

Is it possible to parse this String to a Function and execute it?

Comment: Yes its possible `var fn = eval(funcStr);`. Should you do this ever? **NO**. Also, note the unescaped quotes.

Comment: Side note: use single quotes for nested quotes.

Comment: Maybe you should consider fixing the server; that's a weird thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but not a good idea. You use [`eval`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp). This isn't the best to do for reasons too complex and opinion-based to get into here.

Comment: Please don't answer dupes. Flag for closure instead.

Comment: Why not both? :P